# how to set no tax for wholesaler customer group in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, customer-group, tax-class

If a customer belongs to wholesaler group then tax should not be applied to that customer. Can Anyone help me how can I do this in Magento 2?

Any help will be appreciated. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps I followed for Magento2, which are slightly different from 1.

**Set Up Wholesale Tax Rule**

From admin menu go to Stores > Tax Rates and Add New Tax Rule. Call it something like Wholesale No Tax. Add a new Tax Rate called "Wholesale Tax Rate" and under Tax Groups make sure only the Wholesaler customer group is selected. Set the Priorty to 1 and click Save.

[image: Adding the Tax Rule]

**Edit Customer Group**

Go to Stores->Customer Groups. Click on the Wholesale group. In the “Tax Class” drop down, select your new “Wholesale” tax class, and save it.

**Make Sure Customer Groups Are Applied**

Under Stores->Configuration->Tax and Stores->Configuration->Customers->Customer Configuration->Create New Account Options there are numerous additional options you will need to check to make sure things are working properly.